# How can I use a list in subprocess.Popen to store some values in another list in python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, subprocess, popen

I have 2 mac addresses stored in a list(maclist) and I made them to be "greped" from a file. I think the for-loop is doing its job properly but nothing is being printed in the output(iplist).

The file contains both the mac addresses and the ip so that by using the mac I can get the ip.

```
iplist = []
leasefile="/var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases"

p9 = subprocess.Popen(["cut", "-f", "2,3,4", "-s", "-d", " ", leasefile], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in p9.stdout:
    for i in range(len(maclist)):
        p10 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", str(maclist[i])], stdin=p9.stdout,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

        p11 = subprocess.Popen(["cut", "-f", "2", "-s", "-d", " "], encoding="utf8", 
            stdin=p10.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

        for line2 in p11.stdout:
            iplist.append(line2.rstrip('\n'))
    print(iplist)
```

Comment: Why are you doing this with subproceses instead of just reading the file with Python?